# BrokerNotAvailableError: Could not find the leader Exception while Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-kafka

I have written a Kafka Producer in NodeJS and Kafka Consumer in Java Maven. My topic is "test" which was created by the following command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

Producer in NodeJS:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var Producer = kafka.Producer;
var Client = kafka.Client;
var client = new Client('localhost:2181');
var producer = new Producer(client);

producer.on('ready', function () {
    producer.send([
        { topic: 'test', partition: 0, messages: ["This is the zero message I am sending from Kafka to Spark"], attributes: 0},
        { topic: 'test', partition: 1, messages: ["This is the first message I am sending from Kafka to Spark"], attributes: 0},
        { topic: 'test', partition: 2, messages: ["This is the second message I am sending from Kafka to Spark"], attributes: 0}
        ], function (err, result) {
        console.log(err || result);
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

When I send two messages from NodeJS producer, it successfully consumed by Java Consumer. But when I send three or more messages from NodeJS producer, it gives me following error:

{ [BrokerNotAvailableError: Could not find the leader] message: 'Could not find the leader' }

I want to ask that how can I set LEADER to any message in a topic "test". Or what should be the solution for the issue.

Comment: To achieve more reliability you can run more number of broker and enable replication on the topic so that if leader broker halts other follower broker will take the position and you will run less in Leaders not available situation..

Answer (score 15):

Instead of `partition` use `partitions` (plural key name).

for example:

```
producer.on('ready', function () {
  producer.send([
    { topic: 'test', partitions: 0, messages: ["This is the zero message I am sending from Kafka to Spark"], attributes: 0},
    { topic: 'test', partitions: 1, messages: ["This is the first message I am sending from Kafka to Spark"], attributes: 0},
    { topic: 'test', partitions: 2, messages: ["This is the second message I am sending from Kafka to Spark"], attributes: 0}
  ], function (err, result) {
    console.log(err || result);
    process.exit();
  });
});
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, but can you please tell why we changed `partition` to `partitions`?

Comment: In 2020 this no longer seems to be the case. `partition` (singular) works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The topic was created with 1 partition, however at the producer end you are trying to send messages to 3 partitions, logically Kafka is not supposed to find leader for the other partitions and should throw this exception.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug that can cause this in the current version of `kafka-node`

https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/354

> HighLevelProducer with KeyedPartitioner fails on first send #354
>   When using KeyedParitioner with the HighLevelProducer the first send fails with
>   BrokerNotAvailableError: Could not find the leader
>   Consecutive sends work perfectly.

Also see https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#highlevelproducer-with-keyedpartitioner-errors-on-first-send

Which recommends

> Call client.refreshMetadata() before sending the first message.

This is how I've done that

```
    // Refresh metadata required for the first message to go through
    // https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/pull/378
    client.refreshMetadata([topic], (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.warn('Error refreshing kafka metadata', err);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue. When I was pushing the message or reading the messages where the partition does not exist. Please modify the partition count to the number you need, manually using the following command.

```
> sh kafka-topics.sh --alter --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partitions 2 --topic test
```

After this it would work fine.

Answer by "Miguel Veces" is working but it is wrong because with that change it starts ignoring the partition parameter you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution. I was doing one mistake. By default Apache Kafka create the 3 replication, this means by default it create 3 brokers. However above YAML create only one broker, and looking for other 2 which is not created. hence we are getting the same error.

**Fix**

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    ports:
      - "32181:32181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
    
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    ports:
      - "9094:9094"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms512m -Xmx3000m"
```

then `KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1` tell the Apache kafka that we Wanted to create only one replication and its work.

**Use the below code to publish and consume the kafka message**

```
var intCounter = 104;

    setInterval(() => {
        setMessageInTopic('topic'+intCounter, function(response){
            echo("Producer Response"+response);
            if(response){
                echo("Consumer init");
                getMessageFromKafak(response,function(pStrMessage){
                    echo ("------------------------Consumer message --------------------");
                    echo(pStrMessage);
                });
            }else{
                echo("Error");
            }
        });
        intCounter++; 
    },5000);
    
    
    
function setMessageInTopic(pStrTopicName, callback){
    const kafka = require('kafka-node');

    try {
      const Producer = kafka.Producer;
      const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost:"localhost:9094"});
      const producer = new Producer(client);
      const kafka_topic =  pStrTopicName;
      console.log(kafka_topic);
      let payloads = [
        {
          topic: kafka_topic,
          messages: {'name':'vipin'}
        }
      ];

      producer.on('ready', async function() {
        let push_status = producer.send(payloads, (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('[kafka-producer -> '+kafka_topic+']: broker update failed');
            callback(false);
          } else {
            console.log('[kafka-producer -> '+kafka_topic+']: broker update success');
            callback(pStrTopicName);
          }
        });
      });

      producer.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('[kafka-producer -> '+kafka_topic+']: connection errored');
        callback(false);
        ///throw err;
      });
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      callback(false);
    }
}

function getMessageFromKafak(pStrTopicName, callback){
    try{
        var kafka = require('kafka-node');
        //var HighLevelProducer = kafka.HighLevelProducer;
        var Consumer = kafka.Consumer;
        var client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost:"localhost:9094"});
        
        let consumer = new Consumer(
            client,
            [{ topic: pStrTopicName}],
            {
              autoCommit: true,
              fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000,
              fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
              encoding: 'utf8',
              fromOffset: false
            }
          );
      
        echo("------------------RESPONE MESSAGE PROCESS "+pStrTopicName+" ----------------------")
        consumer.on('message', function (message) {
            echo("------------------RESPONE MESSAGE  ----------------------")
            console.log(message);
            consumer.close();
            client.close();
            return callback(message);
        }).on('error', function (message) {
            echo("------------------RESPONE MESSAGE ERROR ----------------------")
            console.log(message);
            consumer.close();
            client.close();
            return callback(message);
        });
    }catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Happy coding :)

Thanks & Regards
Jaiswar Vipin Kumar R.